# HDF5 built with MS VC++ 2008 and boost 1.39.0 libs in application built with MS VC++ 2010 + boost 1.45.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, hdf5

I upgraded to MS VC++ 2010 (Visual Studio Professional) and boost 1.45.0 but I am still trying to use HDF5 1.8.4p1 built with MS VC++ 2008 and boost 1.39.0; everything builds fine (I provide explicitly the boost_zlib-vc90*.[lib/dll] required in my HDF5 lib path). But when I run I get the following run-time error in HDF5 libraries:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x... in <exec>: 0x... : Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff
```

The error appears to be clearly isolated to the HDF5 libs. The access violation is occurring in the H5File(...) constructor inside the function call below (I confirmed it by separating into two lines of code). I've also tried changing the HDF5 file access flags but to no avail:

```
m_file.reset(new H5::H5File(path, H5F_ACC_RDONLY));
```

Here m_file is of type:

```
boost::shared_ptr<H5::H5File>
```

Do I have no other recourse other than building HDF5 libs with MS VC++ 2010 and boost_zlib 1.45?

Edit:

Just wanted to follow up that I ended up building the HDF5 libs (was a little bit of a pain, but things worked out using the CMake route) on MS VC++ 2010 and my application works fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work, different versions of boost are definetly not binary compatible (any library which makes extensive use of C++ templates is very likely to not be binary compatible with other versions of the same library). 
Same goes presumeably for different versions of the C++ standard library shipped with visual studio.

The only solution is to recompile HDF5 with MSVC10 and boost 1.45.

Comment: Thanks @smerlin. That's what I was hoping to hear.

Comment: +1, absolutely correct. In addition, the everything must be compiled with the same compiler options against the same CRT.

Comment: @ildjarn: its most of the times ok, if the CRT versions differ in minor version numbers (Visual Studio version and Service Pack version must match), but only if linked dynamically, and if the CRT version loaded at runtime is identical (which can be achieved using manifest files).